# Files appear online, but won't sync to my machine

Tags: dropbox

I am running linux mint 11. Shortly after installing someone shared a Dropbox folder with me. That folder syncs online and down to my machine. All of it's immediate subfolders sync online and down to my machine. However, the contents of two of the folders doesn't sync down to my machine. Only sync online. I ran the "Dropbox Bad File Check" and it said that "None" files were a bad file.

Does anyone know what I can try to get it to work? Over time, I have uninstalled dropbox several times. Not sure what to try next.

Answer (score 1):

Try to check if you have enabled Selective Sync (Preferences → Advanced). I did that sometime before and could not get files to sync until I finally found my way back there and realised I had deselected some.